# csv file to list of tuples - excluding certain columns

Tags: list, python-3.x, csv, tuples

I need to create a list of tuples from a .csv file. On another post a member suggested using this code:

```
import csv
with open('movieCatalogue.csv') as f:
    data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]
    data.pop(0)

print(data)
```

This is almost perfect except the first column in the .csv file contains the product id which I do not one in the tuples. Is there a way to prevent certain columns in each line from being copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suppose you're dropping the title line with `data.pop(0)`. You could save a list dealloc/move by skipping when reading.

Then, when you compose your tuple, just drop the first element using sub-list syntax: `line[start:stop:step]`, starting at index 0.

```
import csv
with open('movieCatalogue.csv') as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    # drop the first line: better as next(f)
    # since it works even if the title line is multi-line!
    next(cr)

    data=[tuple(line[1:]) for line in cr]  # drop first column of each line

print(data)
```